# Is System.Data.DataTable available in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to blazor and was trying to use it.
I tried recreating the repeater and was trying to bind it using System.Data.DataTable but it seems to be impossible to do it and also i can't find a way on how to call the rows.

Is there a roundabout way on how to use DataTable in Blazor?

```
 <Repeater2 Items=@dtTest>
    <RepeaterContainerTemplate Context=ItemsContent>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Text A</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Text B</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Text C</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                   @ItemsContent
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </RepeaterContainerTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate Context=test>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center">@test["Text_A"]</td>
             <td class="text-center">@test["Text_B"]</td>
             <td class="text-center">@test["Text_C"]</td>
         </tr>                 
     </ItemTemplate>
 </Repeater2>
```

Comment: I've never used Blazor but I would assume that what you assign to `Items` has to be an `IEnumerable<T>`, which a `DataTable` is not. If you call the `AsEnumerable` extension method on it, then you'll get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, so the `Context` for the `ItemTemplate` would then presumably be a `DataRow`.

Comment: @John I have enough experience with both Webforms and Blazor to see that this is an attempt to reproduce that old paradigm. You'll have a very hard time convincing me that anyone ever should use this kind of generic data table in Blazor.

The only case where that might make sense to me is if a user can arbitrarily add a lot of new Columns of various types as part of program functionality.

Comment: Don't use a DataTable with Blazor, and even strive to avoid it in old stuff like winforms. It's been possible to avoid using it for a long time now; if you must, use a strongly typed one

Answer (score 1):

This is not how to do things in Blazor. I use Dapper for my SQL queries, and my data methods return a  typed `List`. This makes it very easy with Linq to sort, filter, or otherwise manipulate my query results in `foreach` loops in the markup.  This is much easier than the way things used to be done in Winforms or Webforms, where you had to work with data tables, rows and so on in codebehind.

You don't have to create a repeater or any of the asp.net Web Forms  listing objects, because now you can use C# logic in your markup to decide what and how to render, and in my experience  this is infinitely better.

Comment: This `Repeater` is native Blazor, not Web Forms. See [here](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-repeater-component-with-blazor.htm). Given that `AsEnumerable` is LINQ to DataSet, you can still use LINQ sort, filter and otherwise manipulate the data.

Comment: I have enough experience with both Webforms and Blazor to see that this is an attempt to reproduce that old paradigm, as evidenced by the attempt to use a data table at all.  There are very few cases where it would be better, or even as good, to use a generic `Datatable` object rather than a `List` of some custom type.    Explaining to someone new to the framework how to achieve doing something that he shouldn't be doing probably isn't that helpful.

Comment: This answer would benefit from code of "how it should be done" otherwise there's a risk the OP/future visitors will just copypasta the other answer

Comment: @John but even if the datatable is enumerable, you're still having to use stringly typed carp like `(int)row["id"]` or `row.Field<int>("Id")`

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah I'd love to show how to display class fields in a `foreach` loop,  but the OP’s example doesn't really have any kind of indication as to what kind of data the person wants to work with.  I suspect he would benefit from a few videos on YouTube,  as how to edit or display a Model is going to be covered for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Data.DataTable in Blazor application like this

This is your html

```
@using System.Data

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Text A</th>
            <th class="text-center">Text B</th>
            <th class="text-center">Text C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            <td class="text-center">@row["TextA"]</td>
            <td class="text-center">@row["TextB"]</td>
            <td class="text-center">@row["TextC"]</td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is your code behind

```
@code {    
    private System.Data.DataTable table;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        table = new();

        table.Columns.Add("TextA");
        table.Columns.Add("TextB");
        table.Columns.Add("TextC");

        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["TextA"] = "Text_A";
        row["TextB"] = "Text_B";
        row["TextC"] = "Text_C";

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Mmm, it's that meme: "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should"

Comment: @Surinder Singh  I gave you +1 for correctly answering the OP question. However I think the OP actually doing this is a terrible idea. It's much better to load data directly into instances of a model than to load it first into a generic table.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I am agree with what you said. I do not have full context of what asker is trying to achieve, his question was, is it possible to use System.Data.DataTable in Blazor applications and I guided him how he can do it

Answer (score 0):

You can find something similar to this on many sites on the Internet, so I'm just basically regurgitating what's already out there.

`MyTable.razor`

```
@typeparam TRow

@if (this.HeaderRow is not null && this.DataRow is not null && this.DataTable is not null && this.Show)
{
    <table @attributes=UserAttributes>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            @this.HeaderRow
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in DataTable)
        {
            <tr>
                @this.DataRow(item)
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<TRow>? DataTable { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? HeaderRow { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TRow>? DataRow { get; set; }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> UserAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

And here's a version of `FetchData` that uses the component.

```
@page "/fetchdata"
<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

<BaseTable TRow=WeatherForecast DataTable=this.forecasts Show=this.show class="table">
    <HeaderRow>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </HeaderRow>
    <DataRow>
        <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
        <td>@context.TemperatureF</td>
        <td>@context.Summary</td>
    </DataRow>
</BaseTable>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private bool show => forecasts is not null;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Note that I would always use a proper view service for my data management so `WeatherForecast[]` would live in that service and not in the UI.